# Categorical data transformation in Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a 40 million x 22 numpy array of integer data for a classification task.
Most of the features are categorical data that use different integer values to represent different categories. For example, in the column "Color": 0 means blue, 1 means red and so on. I have preprocessed the data using LabelEncoder.

1. Does it make sense to fit those data into any classification model in SK-learn? I tried to fit the data into Random Forest model but got extremely bad accuracy. I also tried One Hot Encoding to transform the data into dummy variables, but my computer can only deal with a sparse matrix after using One Hot Encoding, the problem is that Random Forest can only take a dense matrix, which will exceed my computer's memory.
2. What's the correct strategy to deal with categorical data in SK-learn?

Comment: I would cut down your training data size and figure out which features are the most useful first before trying to process 40 million rows of data. RandomForest has an attribute `feature_importances_` which will tell you what it reckons are the most useful features: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#feature-importance-evaluation

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't know sklearn has that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LabelEncoder` is useless in your case, since output numbers do not make any sense as numbers (i.e. it's meaningless to perform arithmetic operations on them). `OneHotEncoder` is essential when dealing with categorical data.

Recently sklearn [got support for sparse input](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3173) in Random Forests and Decision Trees, so you might want to check out the latest version. Also, other methods like [LogisticRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) support sparse data.

Moreover, I don't think you need to use all 40M of examples to get a decent accuracy. It should be enough to randomly sample, say, 100k of them (this number depends on number of features after OneHotEncoding, their variability, and number of target classes).

Comment: Wow! that's good news! I am currently using the latest stable version 0.15.2. Should I update to the latest development version?. Sorry I don't know how to find the right version for that git merge.

Comment: @JimGB, I'm not familiar with sklearn's version policy, so when I needed Random Forests with sparsity, I just checked out `master`.